# How do I find out what I can do with the Pelican signals? I'm trying to write a plugin

Tags: python, pelican

The signals are sort-of described [here](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/plugins.html) but, then what?

For example, one of the signals is desribed:

> invoked before writing each article, the article is passed as content

How do I change that content? How do I access it? What functions are available?

I've been looking at examples in the pelican plugins repo on github, but I'm still confused. (How did those people even learn how to write those plugins?)

I hardly know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

You have to look at the [source code](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican) of `pelican`. I think there is no better way.

For example, search for the signal you are interested in, e.g. `article_generator_write_article`: https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=article_generator_write_article

Then, look into the search result, e.g. `generators.py` and click on the line number containing your signal. Of course, you could also create a clone and do all this locally. This depends on your way of working.

Surrounding code:

```
def generate_articles(self, write):
    """Generate the articles."""
    for article in chain(self.translations, self.articles):
        signals.article_generator_write_article.send(self, content=article)
        write(article.save_as, self.get_template(article.template),
              self.context, article=article, category=article.category,
              override_output=hasattr(article, 'override_save_as'), blog=True)
```

As you can see, the signal call provides you with an `article` object. You can now 1) look in the source code to find the respective python class of this object to find out about its inner workings, methods and attributes or 2) go the hacky path and simply print the object's members `print(article.__dict__)`.

I suppose, without having looked in the code, that `article` has an attribute `content` which contains the HTML code generated from your source file. This is where your desired change comes in.

Note that if you want to change the source code **before processing** this is not that easy. I just wrote a little [plugin](https://github.com/mhoff/pelican-global-rst-include) which is capable of doing this.

There you can also see the signal API in action. You simply have to `connect` a handler function to the desired signal.

I hope this helps :)